# Text and Figure side by side inside a minipage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have a two column CV. I made the columns using minipage. In the second minipage (second column), I want my picture and some info in two columns.

How do I do this?

This is the relevant section of my CV.

```
\section{Profile}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{cvpic.jpg}

\end{minipage} % End right-hand side of the page
\end{document}
```

It shows up like this

[image: bottom right corner]

Comment: You can have minipages in minipages, i.e. nest them.